# How do I speed up a nested for-loop in Python with large datasets?

Tags: python, performance, cython

For every element in list A, I need to calculate the Levenshtein distance between it and every element in list B. It's 375 million calculations total, which will take too long (over 10 hours) with the nested for-loop that I currently have below:

```
for a in range(10000):
    listA_element = listA[a]
    
    # Calculate the levenshtein distance between the listA element and every listB element
    for b in range(50000):
        listB_element = listB[b]
        score = abd.DiscountedLevenshtein().sim(listA_element, listB_element)
```

How can I do what the code above does, but in under 1-2 hours? I have looked into using NumPy but it seems that will not work with the levenshtein distance library, and I need the flexibility to do several different things in the loops other than calculations (creating lists, appending to lists, etc). I am having issues with the Cython route, so any alternatives are welcome.

Comment: I think it may be hard to beat the performance of the code above if you are set on using the `abd.DiscountedLevenshtein().sim` function, but if you are able to find a way to do it using matrix operations in numpy it will be fast. Reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Iterative_with_full_matrix) it seems like there are matrix operations which can do levenshein distance, so maybe there is a way to convert each letter in each string in list a into a number in a np.array and all characters in each word in B into another np.array then do some sort of vectorized compare

Comment: It is possible, but will require quite a work. You would need to rewrite [this function](https://abydos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/abydos/distance/_discounted_levenshtein.html#DiscountedLevenshtein.dist), using the fact that part of the computations there is repeated in your for loop. You are using the same strings. You could use caching to make it simpler. And first use line_profiler to check what is your bottleneck there